# Existence of a probability over a discrete set of numbers

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given $\omega = \left\{1,2,3,4,5,6\right\}$, $\ A = \sigma(\left\{1,2,3,4\right\}, \left\{3,4,5,6\right\})$.

(a) List all subsets of $A$.

(b) Is the function $B(x) = 2$ for $x = 1,2,3,4$ and $=7$ for $x=5,6$ a random variable on $(\omega, A)$?

(c) Give an example of function $f$ on $\omega$ s.t $f$ is not a random variable over $(\omega, A)$.

(d) Prove that there is a probability $P$ over $(\omega, A)$ such that $P(C) = 1$ or $0$ for any $C\in A$, but $P$ is not a point mass.

**My attemp** For (a), $A = \left\{\left\{1,2\right\},\left\{3,4\right\}, \left\{5,6\right\}, \left\{1,2\right\}\cup\left\{3,4\right\}, \left\{1,2\right\}\cup\left\{5,6\right\}, \left\{3,4\right\}\cup\left\{5,6\right\}, \emptyset, \omega\right\}$.

For (b), I think $B$ is NOT a random variable because if $B$ is, then for some values of $x$ such that $B(x) = 7$, the number $7$ must be in Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $w$, which is impossible (by definition of $w$).

For (c),well, change the number $7$ to any other constants that do not belong to $w$ (for example, $8$), and use the same argument as in (b).

For (d), I am confused on how to approach this part, because based on the given definition of $P$, isn't $P$ a point mass (I meant, isn't the fact that $P(A) = 0$ or $1$ implies $P$ is a point mass. Unless what this means is that $A$ is a set of more than one element?).

**Question** Could someone help review my solution to parts **(b) + (c)** above, and give some thought on (d)?

Comment: Re (b), your approach is wrong and you should check the definition of being a random variable.

Comment: The definition of a random variable is a function $X = \left\{x: B(x)\in B(\omega)\right\}$ where $B$ is a Borel set over $\omega$. So due to the condition that $B(x)\in B(\omega)$ and $B(\omega)$ only contains elements $1,2,3,4,5,6$, $X$ only contains $1,2,3,4$? So $B(x)$ is indeed a random variable. So for part (c), I only need to define B(x) = 2 for $x = 1,2,3,4,7$. Then $B(x)\in B(\omega)$ is satisfied, but $X$ has element $7$ which is not in $B(\omega)$. Is this correct now? And could you try part (d)?

Comment: Conjecture confirmed: you have no definition of the notion of random variable at hand. **Please check a source**. That A does not even appear in the definition you propose, should worry you...

Comment: Suddenly $w$ shows up in your question. Is it a typo and did you mean $\omega$? And what do you mean with [Borel $\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#Borel_and_Lebesgue_.CF.83-algebras) of $w$? That concept only makes sense if a topology is involved. They can be missed if it comes to the existence of random variables.

Comment: @drhab: it's the same set $w$ given. I think I messed up on that Borel $\sigma$-algebra of w. Could you help verify if this proof for part (b) is correct: let $C$ be any subset of $\mathscr{B}(R)$, then $B^{-1}{C} =  \emptyset$ if $2,\ 7\not\in C$, $= {1,2,3,4}$ if $2\in C, 7\not\in C$, $={5,6}$ if  $2\not\in C, 7\in C$, $\omega$ if $2, 7\in C$.  This means $B^{-1}{C}\in A$, so the given function is random variable.

But now, I could not come up with an example for part (c). Could you help with (c)+(d)?

Comment: @Did: could you help verify if my new proof in the comment above is correct? Sorry, for those $B^{-1}C$, it means $B^{-1}(C)$.

Comment: @drhab: I think for part (c), just add another element not in $w$, like $B(x) = 7$ for $x = 8$. Then the set $B^{-1}(C)$ contains element $8$, which does not belong to $A$, so $B$ is not a random variable. But I am not sure if we have to restrict the domain of $B$ to only elements in the sample space $\omega$. Any thought?

Comment: "I think for part (c), just add another element not in w" ?? Sorry but when I put side by side the fact that this sentence is plainly absurd and the fact that you still declined to produce a definition of the very notion of random variable, I cannot help to think that these are related. Usually people consider they should first learn the definitions and then solve some related exercises, but your choice is to proceed otherwise, right?

Comment: @Did: I did provide the definition of random variable: it is a function $X: \omega \rightarrow R$ such that for any $B\subset \mathscr{B}(R)$, then $X^{-1}(B)\in F$ where $F$ is a sigma-algebra of $\omega$. I don't understand why you keep refusing to help me, because I already provided the solution for part (b) in my comment above(the 4th one from the bottom).

Comment: @user177196 In explicit contradiction with what you pretend, your last comment is the first time we see a definition, but better late than never I guess. "I don't understand why you keep refusing to help me" Wow. You do not think that pointing the notions you lack and you need to understand a solution is "helping"? OK, your call.

Comment: @Did: I did not mean that. I meant after I pointed out the definition, and show my work, you still did not offer some help regards to my proof or how to approach parts (c)+(d) above.

Comment: "after I pointed out the definition" Where did you do that (no, the comment you point at does not contain a definition)? OK, it seems this exchange is leading nowhere so, if indeed you think your approach to learning a subject without knowing the definitions (or with shaky ones) is optimal, good for you.

Comment: For (d), note that $\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}$ are "atoms" of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, so you can assign them any probabilities you like (as long as these probabilities are non-negative and sum to $1$). So why not make one of these atoms have probability $1$ and the others $0$?

Comment: @carmichael561: the thing is that we need to have the countably additivity satisfied. So, if only one of them has probability $1$ (for example, $\left\{1,2\right\}$), then $P(\left\{1,2\right\}\cap \left\{3,4\right\}) = P((\left\{1,2,3,4\right\})=0$, while $P(\left\{1,2\right\}) + P(\left\{3,4\right\}) = 1$.

Comment: If $\mathbb{P}(\{1,2\})=1$ and $\mathbb{P}(\{3,4\})=0$, then $\mathbb{P}(\{1,2,3,4\})=1$ by countable additivity, so there's no problem. What I'm saying is specify the probabilities of the atoms $\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}$, and this will determine the probabilities of the other elements of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: I thought we have to determine all of those probabilities before-hand, and then verify that $P$ is actually a probability over $\omega$? But I think I got your point. We're working backwards to get those values by assuming $P$ is a probability!! I'm so dumb:((

Comment: Ok, so I think we need to define these: $P(\left\{1,2\right\}) = P(\left\{1,2,3,4\right\}) = P(\left\{1,2,5,6\right\}) = P(\left\{1,2,3,4,5,6\right\} = 1$, and the remaining elements of $A$ has probability $ 0$. Is this true?

Comment: @carmichael561: could you help review my solution to this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922201/random-variable-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) correct.

b) The question makes no real sense to me. If there is a [measurable space](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeasurableSpace.html) $\langle\omega,\mathcal A\rangle$ and $B$ denotes a function $\omega\to\mathbb R$ then you cannot speak yet of a random variable (so formally your answer ($B$ is not a random variable) is correct, but this on other grounds). For that you also need a probability measure $\Pr$ on $\mathcal A$. The triple  $\langle\omega,\mathcal A,\Pr\rangle$ is a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space). An appropriate rephrasing of the question is: "Is function $B$ measurable?" and the answer to that question is yes: all preimages under $B$ of Borelsets of $\mathbb R$ are all elements of $\mathcal A$.

c) Same story about random variable. Rephrasing: does there exist a function $f:\omega\to\mathbb R$ that is not measurable? Yes, can you find one yourself? Try to find a function such that the preimage of some Borel subset of $\mathbb R$ under it will not be in $\mathcal A$. Hint: "almost all" subsets of $\mathbb R$ that we are usually dealing with are Borelsets. Singletons too. Your idea to start working with $\omega\cup\{7\}$ makes no sense.

d) If you can find a probability space $\Pr$ on $\langle\omega,\mathcal A\rangle$ such that $\Pr(C)\in\{0,1\}$ for every $C\in\mathcal A$ then you are ready. This because $\mathcal A$ does not contain any "points", i.e. singletons, hence automatically $\Pr$ is not a point-mass.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. So basically, for part (d), we need to define $P(C) = 0$ for $C\notin A$, and$P(C) = 1$ for $C in A$? 

For part (c), the only case where I think i could get the preimage of some Borel subsets of R under it will not be in $A$ is when I define $f(w) = 1$ for $w=1$, and $f(w) = 2$ for $w = 2,3,4,5,6$. This means for any $B\in \mathscr{B}(R)$, we could never have $f^{-1}(B) = \left\{1\right\}$ if $B=\left\{1\right\}$, since this is a singleton set, which is not contained in $A$. Is this correct?

Comment: d) If $C\notin\mathcal A$ then $P(C)$ is **not defined**. So it makes no sense  to say that $P(C)=0$ for $C\notin\mathcal A$. Hint: Pick out some (small, but not too small) $C\in\mathcal A$ and define $P(C)=1$. Then try to find the values of $P$ on the other sets of $\mathcal A$ keeping in mind that $P$ as probability measure has certain properties.

Comment: c) Your $f$ works, but your reasoning is vague. If $f$ is defined as you suggest then $f^{-1}(\{1\})=\{1\}\notin\mathcal A$. So Borelset $\{1\}\subset\mathbb R$ has not a measurable (i.e. belongs to $\mathcal A$) preimage. Then $f$ is not measurable. "the only case"... well there are much more.

Comment: my apology for my stupidness. I did not pay attention to the fact $P(C) = 0$ is impossible:p so what you meant is that I should define P(C_i) = 1/n_i for any $C_i\in A - C$, $C_i$ are disjoint events and $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} C_i = A-C$. There exists such $C_i$ due to disjointification.

Comment: What I meant was: set e.g. $P(\{1,2\})=1$ and then find $P(C)$ for all $C\in\mathcal A$ on base of the properties of a probability measure. If you do that correctly then you will notice that $P(C)\in\{0,1\}$ for all $C\in\mathcal A$, as requested.

Comment: Wait a minute. So I think the only way to do that CORRECTLY is to have: $P(C) = 1$ for $C=\omega$, and $P(C) = 0$ for $C\in A, C\neq \omega$. This is because we need to make sure $P$ satisfies the condition that $P(\omega)=1$, as $A$ contains $\omega$. For the 3rd condition, for example, with 2 sets $\left\{1,2\right\}$ and $\left\{3,4\right\}$, we have: $P(\left\{1,2\right\}\cup \left\{3,4\right\}) = 0 = P(\left\{1,2\right\}) +  P(\left\{3, 4\right\})$ by the definition of P defined above. For the 1st condition, it's obvious that our $P\geq 0$ for any $C\in A$. Is this true now?

Comment: nevermind. It doesn't work, as I would have the case that $P(\left\{1,2\right\}\cup \left\{3,4\right\}\cup \left\{5,6\right\}) = P(\omega) = 1$ by our definition, while the sum of these 3 elements $= 0$:( I'm struggled now:p

Comment: If $P(\{1,2\})=1$ then **necessarily** $P(\{3,4\})=P(\{5,6\})=P(\{7,8\})=0$. This because $P(\{1,2\})+P(\{3,4\})+P(\{5,6\})+P(\{7,8\})=P(\omega)=1$ and probabilities do not take negative values.

Comment: thank you for your patience. We also need $P(\left\{1,2,3,4\right\}) = P(\left\{1,2,5,6\right\})=1$ while the probability of each remaining other sets $=0$. I think this is the sufficient condition to have $P$ satisfies the $3$ required properties.

Comment: Yes. For every set in $C\in\mathcal A$ that contains $\{1,2\}$ as a subset we have $P(C)=1$ and for the others in $\mathcal A$ we have $P(C)=0$. So $P(C)\in\{0,1\}$ for every $C\in\mathcal A$ as requested.