# Sigma-algebra of Borel measurable function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $Y= f(X)$ where $X$ is a random variable and $f: R\rightarrow R$ is Borel measurable. Show that $\sigma(Y)\subset \sigma(X)$. Also, show that if $X=g(Y)$ for some $g$, then $\sigma(X) = \sigma(Y)$.

**My thought** Since $f: R\rightarrow R$ is Borel measurable, for every $t\in R$,  $\ f^{-1}((-\infty, t])\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$. $X$ is a random variable implies $X^{-1}((-\infty, t])\in F$ for any $t∈ \mathbb{R}$ ($F = \sigma(\mathbb{R})$). Since $\sigma(Y) = \sigma(f(X))$, I only need to show that $f(X)\subset X$. But I could not see why is this true?

Could anyone please help on this part and the 2nd part as well. Really appreciate your thought.

Comment: I suggest consistently using upper-case $X$ for your random variable.  Your statement at the end, $f(X) \subset X$ makes no sense; these are random variables, not sets.  I am also not sure what $\sigma(R)$ is supposed to denote.

Comment: I want to add that $f(X) \subset X$ is not necessarily true (and, as the answer illustrates, is not what you need to show).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, if $Y=f(X)$ then for any Borel set $B$ we have
$$ Y^{-1}(B)=\{\omega:f(X(\omega))\in B\}=\{\omega:X(\omega)\in f^{-1}(B)\}=X^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))\subset\sigma(X) $$
because $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set. Since $B$ was any Borel set, this shows that $\sigma(Y)\subset\sigma(X)$.

For the second part, if also $X=g(Y)$ then interchanging the roles of $X$ and $Y$ in the first part shows that $\sigma(X)\subset \sigma(Y)$, and since we already know that $\sigma(Y)\subset\sigma(X)$, this shows that the two $\sigma$-algebras are equal.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have a question: In your proof for the forward direction, only the last part uses the fact that $X$ is a random variable? How do we know that $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set?

Comment: One of the hypotheses of the question was that $f$ is Borel measurable. This means precisely that $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set for every Borel set $B$.

Comment: True! I just check that fact:p My apology.  Thank you for your great solution once again.

Could you again help me with the last problem here (part (d) only): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920853/existence-of-a-probability-over-a-discrete-set-of-numbers?noredirect=1#comment3944684_1920853